# text resize with php while using GD functions

Tags: php

I did found a topic similar to this, but I do not know if the solution is the same. So here is my question:

I'm using the GD functions to bild a web card generating program. The thing is that the card's backgound is generating by the `$image = imagecreatefrompng();` function. 
The card need's also a `$cardname` as "title" and a `$desription` as desription. For that I used the `imagettftext();` function. But there is a problem, the card's size is 333x485, I need the text to be resized in order to fit in the background without resizing its height, but only the width!

To be more to the point, the `$cardname` should have `width = 240` and `height = 34`, but if it doesn't  fit, it goes off the background, I need a function that will resize its width in order to fit in 240px and leave the height to 34px always!

To understand it more look here: http://yugiohcardmaker.net. in the "name" you can add as much text you like, it will always fit in and in the right width and height!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to try and code this as it will take too long, but here's the basic process:

1. Get the size of the bounding box for your text with imagettfbbox();
2. Create a new image with imagecreatetruecolor();
3. Write your text into your new image with imagettftext();
4. Use imagecopyresampled() to copy the new image with your text to your existing card, setting the parameters to shrink the width but not the height.

Note: the bounding box parameters returned by `imagettfbbox())` can be fiddly to work with
You'll also need to be careful about alphablending and background colors to ensure that only your text pixels are copied.

Good luck!

Comment: Thought so. Still, as I recall, imagettfbbox(); use coordinates instead of pixels. How do I will know the exact coodinates in order to create the imagebox?

Comment: The coordinates are measured in pixels, so a bit of arithmetic is all you need to get the dimensions. Be careful with the exact order of the coordinates. I find it useful to sketch out what I want and fill the numbers in on the sketch. As I said - it can be fiddly.

Comment: also... I must get transparent background for the "title". How do I do that??

Comment: I used `imagecolortransparent();` to get the background transparent, but text is blur with some black pixels. Do you know any better way to do it more HQ?